# Convolution equation in the space of rapidly decreasing functions

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I wonder if you can help me out with the following problem:

> Find all $u \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})$ such that there is an $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})$ for which $u- u \ast f= f \ast f$.

I think it should be solved using the fourier transform but I'm not sure how. 
Since $u,f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})$ we have  $u \ast f, f \ast f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})$ and one is allowed to take the Fourier transform to get
$\hat{f}(\xi)^2, \hat{u}(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi) \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})$  which gives the equation $\hat{u}(1-\hat{f})=\hat{f}^2$. I'm not really sure what to do with this though (or if it's the right way to go). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You obtain $u = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\frac{\hat{f}^2}{1-\hat{f}}]$ where $\frac{\hat{f}^2}{1-\hat{f}}$ has to be Schwartz, which is the case if $\hat{f}$ is Schwartz and $|\hat{f}(\xi) -1| \ge  c >0$. Finally, discuss if every Schwartz function $u$ can be written in this form.

Comment: Ok thanks! If $|\hat{f}(\xi) -1|>0 $ either $\hat{f}(\xi) >1$ or $\hat{f}(\xi) <1$ but since $\hat{f}(\xi) \to 0$ as $\xi \to \pm \infty$ one has to have $\hat{f}(\xi) <1$..? Is this correct? Is it possible to say more than this?

Comment: If $\hat f(\xi)$ certainly was real, then your conclusion $\hat f(\xi)>1$ or $\hat f(\xi)<1$ would have been correct. But $\hat f(\xi)$ might be complex.

Comment: Hmm... so the range of $\hat{f}$ is $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{1 \}$? I'm actually out of ideas here.

Comment: I suppose that @reuns can expand on his argument.

Comment: @md2perpe $\hat{f}(\xi)^2+\hat{f}(\xi) \hat{u}(\xi)-\hat{u}(\xi) = 0$ is a quadratic equation in $\hat{f}(\xi)$

Comment: So we can solve for $\hat f(\xi)$ and since $\hat u$ is complex and continuous, we don't have problems with the square root in the solution. Correct, @reuns?

Comment: @md2perpe The problem is $\hat{u}(\xi) = 0 \implies \hat{f}(\xi) = 0$ and $\hat{f} \in C^\infty$ constrains its "zeros" to be of integer (or infinite) order.

Comment: @reuns. So $\hat u$ may not have any zeros?

Comment: @md2perpe of odd order (the order of a zero $a$ of a smooth function $g$ is the $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(a+x)}{x^k} = C \ne 0$. If no such $k$ exists we can say $k=\infty$)

Comment: Right. And then we should try to translate this from a condition on $\hat u$ to a condition on $u$.